# Playing and Stopping Sound with JS and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, pause

I have a way to play sound with a simple command, https://github.com/admsev/jquery-play-sound, but the audio file I am playing is about 2 minutes long. I need a way to stop/silence the audio with a javascript or jquery command. Does anyone know how I could do this? I don't really want a button that stops the sound unless it was a regular html button that could do other things besides stop the sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery playSound](https://github.com/admsev/jquery-play-sound) library you linked does not support pausing. I think it would be best to choose a different library that supports pausing so you don’t have to write that functionality yourself.

I used the [howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/) library before and it worked fine for me. Here is how you would use howler.js:

```html
<!-- to load the library on the page -->
<script src="howler.js">
```

```js
// to create and play the sound
var backgroundMusic = new Howl({
  urls: ['music.mp3', 'music.ogg'],
}).play();

// to pause the sound
// (make sure the variable `backgroundMusic` is accessible)
backgroundMusic.pause();

// to stop the sound
backgroundMusic.stop();
```

Comment: Would I have to put the .play() on the var or could I do backgroundMusic.play()?

Comment: Yes, you could do `var backgroundMusic = …` and then `backgroundMusic.play()`. That would also let you start the downloading of the music before the user presses Play, if you don’t start playing on page load.

Answer (score 1):

No jQuery, no plugins, just a browser. This is one button that plays and pauses one MP3. You didn't specify what extra things you wanted one single button to do, so I didn't add any extra functions to that one single lonely button. What other things did you want this one solitary button to do?

Btw, if you want the audio to stop instead of pause:

- There's a line in the `<style>` block that you need to uncomment and a line to comment.
- There's a line in the `<script>` block you need to uncomment.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    .play:before {
      content: '\25b6';
    }
    .pause:before {
      content: '\275a\275a';  /*Uncomment this line for pause */
      /* content: '\25a0'; */ /*Uncomment this line for stop */
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <button id="button" class="play">
    <audio id="audio" src="http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/pf-righteous.mp3"></audio>
  </button>

  <script>
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    var button = document.getElementById('button');

    button.addEventListener('click', playPause, false);

    function playPause() {
      if (!audio.paused) {
        audio.pause();
        // audio.currentTime = 0; // Uncomment this line for stop
        button.classList.remove('pause');
        button.classList.add('play');
      } else {
        audio.play();
        button.classList.remove('play');
        button.classList.add('pause');
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It’s good to avoid libraries when you don’t need them. However, sometimes libraries are necessary to smooth over browser-specific differences. [The difference I once ran into](https://github.com/roryokane/vetinari-clock-simulator/commit/c19a2e95c0e444a37ddffeda3f412816529dae20) was that on Firefox for Android, you can’t `.play()` a sound again after it stops playing. Switching to howler.js fixed that – though of course adding a library also made my page load a bit slower. Either solution could be best, depending on what functionality you need and what browsers you support.